# Emgucv Houghlines length of line

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, hough-transform

I`am using EmguCV houghines with edge detector app for detection of ablation rods (rod from wood with red and white stripes), and I need to know, how I get line length in pixels, like: *line one is 50px long*.

Sample of code

```
class HoughTransform
{
    private Image<Gray, Byte> _sourceImage;
    private Image<Gray, Byte> _linesImage;
    private Image<Gray, Byte> _resultImage;

    public HoughTransform()
    {

    }

    public void applyTransform()
    {
        try
        {
            _linesImage = _sourceImage.CopyBlank();
            LineSegment2D [] lines = _sourceImage.HoughLinesBinary(1, Math.PI/ 0.0, 50, 100, 1)[0];
            foreach(LineSegment2D line in lines)
            {
                _linesImage.Draw(line,new Gray(200), 5);
            }
            _resultImage = _linesImage;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation for [LineSegment2D](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/1.4.0.0/html/670b89e1-a8d7-c792-5c1c-fecf6c31d2dd.htm), the length of line is available via the Length property.

```
line.Length
```